# SVN post-commit hook: find folder/commit path

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, client-side-scripting

So I need a client side hook script that gets the file path from the latest commit. 
We have a main repo with several projects in it:

```
Repo
...Project1
......SLN File
...Project 2
```

and so forth.

I know if I was server side I could use `svnlook changed` command. 
However I am stuck client side.

So I was looking into using `svn info` to get the latest rev number ( after `svn update` of course) and then using that rev number with `svn log -c REV# -v`. Then search the  string output of the `svn log` command to get the file paths.

This however is much messier then the `svnlook changed` command. Is there a cleaner way of getting the file or project path on the client side? Ultimately I want the project's path (so Repo/Project1) but I would even take the full file paths for the commit at this point if there was an easier way to obtain that path.